# Angular remove/filter duplicate nationality from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, duplicates, ngfor

I have a two dropdown selects, one for country and one for nationality.
Both dropdowns share an array: countryAndNationalityList.

I'm trying to only display the matching nationality once, as it is the same for each country.

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="residence_country">
    <option *ngFor="let item of removeNationalityDuplicates(countryAndNationalityList.sort(sortCountryAsc))" [ngValue]="item.country">{{item.country}}</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" formControlName="nationality">
    <option value="" disabled>Your Nationality?</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of countryAndNationalityList.sort(sortNationalityAsc)" [ngValue]="item.nationality">{{item.nationality}}</option>
</select>
```

My countryAndNationalityList array looks like this:

```
[{country: "United Arab Emirates Abu Dhabi", nationality: "Emirati"},
{country: "United Arab Emirates Ajman", nationality: "Emirati"},
{country: "United Arab Emirates Al-Quwain", nationality: "Emirati"},
{country: "United Arab Emirates Dubai", nationality: "Emirati"},
{country: "United Arab Emirates Fujairah", nationality: "Emirati"},
{country: "United Arab Emirates Ras Al Khaimah", nationality: "Emirati"},
{country: "United Arab Emirates Sharjah", nationality: "Emirati"}]
```

I am trying to remove the duplicate Emirati in the Nationality dropdown using a function: removeNationalityDuplicates that remove duplicates like this:

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="nationality">
    <option value="" disabled>Your Nationality?</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of removeNationalityDuplicates(countryAndNationalityList.sort(sortNationalityAsc))" [ngValue]="item.nationality">{{item.nationality}}</option>
</select>
```

where removeNationalityDuplicates is

```
  removeNationalityDuplicates(array) {
    return [... new Set(array)];
  }

  sortNationalityAsc(previous, next) {
    return previous.nationality > next.nationality;
  }
```

I have also tried using:

```
removeNationalityDuplicates(array) {
  return array.reduce((uniqueArr, curVal)=> {
    if (!uniqueArr.includes(curVal.nationality)) {
      uniqueArr.push(curVal);
    }
    return uniqueArr;
  }, []);
}
```

How do remove the duplicate nationalities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
removeNationalityDuplicates(array) {
  return Array.from(new Set(array.map(x => x.nationality)));
}
```

Explanation:

1. `array.map(x => x.nationality)` create a new array with only the `nationality` key
2. `new Set(array.map(x => x.nationality))` create a set of this array ( works like distinct )
3. `Array.from(new Set(array.map(x => x.nationality)));` convert the set to an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for a possiblity to *filter* the original array but without changing its properties, use this solution:

```js
const removeNationalityDuplicates = (arr) => [...new Map(arr.map(item => [item.nationality, item])).values()]


const list = [{
    country: "United Arab Emirates Abu Dhabi",
    nationality: "Emirati"
  },
  {
    country: "United Arab Emirates Ajman",
    nationality: "Emirati"
  },
  {
    country: "United Arab Emirates Al-Quwain",
    nationality: "Emirati"
  },
  {
    country: "United Arab Emirates Dubai",
    nationality: "Emirati"
  },
  {
    country: "United Arab Emirates Fujairah",
    nationality: "Emirati"
  },
  {
    country: "United Arab Emirates Ras Al Khaimah",
    nationality: "Emirati"
  },
  {
    country: "United Arab Emirates Sharjah",
    nationality: "Emirati"
  }
]

console.log(removeNationalityDuplicates(list))
```

If you'd wish to have only the list of nationalities, look at [enno.void's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63254592/4892206).